# Elixir: pattern match function arguments to struct

Tags: struct, pattern-matching, elixir

Using [{:typed_struct, "~> 0.2.1"}](https://github.com/ejpcmac/typed_struct/tree/v0.2.1) library I have following struct:

```
  defmodule RequestParams do
    use TypedStruct
    typedstruct do
      field :code, String.t()
      field :name, String.t()
    end
  end
```

I am trying to pattern match function parameters to struct:

```
def do_handle(params %RequestParams{}, _context) do
# instead of
# def do_handle(%{ "code" => code, "name" => name}, _context) do
```

But I get exception:

> ```
> cannot find or invoke local params/2 inside match. Only macros can be
> invoked in a match and they must be defined before their invocation.
> ```

What is wrong? And is it possible at all to match function parameters to struct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Cause of the issue

In [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir), parentheses in function calls are not mandatory (although desirable.) That said, the code `def foo(bar baz) do ...` is being parsed and treated as `def foo(bar(baz)) do ...` because the parser suggests omitted parentheses in call to the function `bar`. You should have got a *warning* from the compiler, saying exactly that. Warnings are supposed to be read and eliminated.

#### Quick fix

As it is pointed out by @peaceful-james, pattern matching inside parentheses would do.

```rb
def do_handle(%RequestParams{} = params, _context) do
```

#### “Instead of”

You wrote

```rb
def do_handle(params %RequestParams{}, _context) do
# instead of
# def do_handle(%{ "code" => code, "name" => name}, _context) do
```

Even if it was syntactically correct, the code above is **not** equivalent to the code below. The code below would accept any map, having two keys `"code"` and `"name"`, while the code above allows instances of `RequestParams` only. One might also make the code below more strict with:

```rb
def do_handle(%RequestParams{code: code, name: name}, _) do
```

#### Struct keys

But structs in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) cannot have anything but `atom` as a key. That said, if your initial code accepted `%{"code" => _}` there is no way to turn it into accepting a struct without modifying the calling code.

#### Typed stuff

Types are not the first-class citizens in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir). I personally find it appropriate. You should start with understanding the language, OTP principles, the paradigm of the language *and only after that* decide whether you want and/or need types at all.

Answer (score 3):

Do you actually mean to write this:

```
def do_handle(%RequestParams{}=params, _context) do
```